# Linked Lists With No Imports

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list, either double or single without using any imports, it's part of a class project. but what i'm not understanding i guess is how to actually create and add an item to the list, without using java.util.
I have

```
public boolean insertItem( ItemType newItem)
{
    if( p==0 || m==MAX_LENGTH)
    {
        head.elem = elem;
        head.next = tail; 
        tail = head;
        return false;
    } 
    else
    {
        tail.next = new ListNode(); //adds new node to the end of the list
        tail = tail.next;//set the tail pointer to that node
        tail.elem = newItem;  //set elem to be stored to the end node
        m++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

so i'd love some input on why this doesn't work. and how i actually create this list, i've been using an array just `Object list[] = new list[MAX_LENGTH]` but i'm not sure if that's the right way to go about it.

Comment: Step #1 Fix formatting in posted and in project. Step #2 Foster and apply some kind of consistent formatting.

Comment: And no, **it's the wrong way to go**. See [Wikipedia: Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) -- that's the data-structure that this assignment calls for. Each cell has a value and a "pointer" to the next (and possibly previous). **Do not use arrays** -- the list structure is self-contained in the cells and links.

Comment: you don't have to use import to use java.util

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with something like:

```
class LinkedList
{
    static class Node
    {
         ItemType item;
         Node next;
         Node prev; // if making a doubly linked list
    }

    private Node head;
    private Node tail; // if making a doubly linked list

    public boolean insertItem(ItemType item)
    {   
        // make a new Node         
        // check for the head to be null...
        // add the node to the end of the list, or make the head/tail point at it.
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, how about making it generic: ´Node<TypeToStore>´ and ´LinkedList<TypeToStore>´

Comment: I would do that... but guessing that is beyond the homework... LinkedList<T> and Node<T> would do it

Answer (score 1):

And no, **it's the wrong way to go**.

See [Wikipedia: Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) -- that's the data-structure that this assignment calls for. Each cell has a value and a "pointer" to the next (and possibly previous).

**Do not use arrays** -- the list structure is self-contained in the cells and links.

Consider this signature to add a new item: (Once the basic operation is understood/implemented, this can be trivially folded back into a method.)

```
static LinkedList insert(LinkedList item, LinkedList newItem) {
   // Update item to "point to" newItem and have newItem "point to" where
   // item used to "point to". Return the new "head" of this
   // segment.

   // Notes:
   // `item` may be null to "insert at start of empty list"
   // This function should be *static* and should only modify
   // item and newItem.
}
```

Usage cases:

```
LinkedList head = insert(null, new LinkedList("a"));
insert(head, new LinkedList("b"));
length(head); // should be 2, cons cells should look like `("a", ("b", null))`
insert(head, new LinkedList("c"));
length(head); // should be 3, cons cells should look like `("a", ("c", ("b", null)))`
```

Remember that `LinkedList` object above refers to a single "cell" with two (or three) members: "the value", "next" (and optionally, "prev"). Depending upon preference, etc., `Node` or `Cell` may be a more suitable name to leave `LinkedList` to refer to the standard collection and/or outside container.

Happy homeworking.

---

Note: The `LinkedList` in the Java collection API is a container which uses a linked-list as an underlying implementation. As such, it misses out of a number of nice use-cases of linked-lists often employed in functional-ish programming languages.